# Spring Data Source is an unknown property?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to configure my data source in application properties resource and getting a yellow warning that spring data source is an unknown property. Error is coming up with all pasted line below.

How to properly configure it so i can get rid of this error?

I have checked the pom.xml and mysql and jpa dependencies are also imported correctly. 
This is my first project so i don't know how to solve this error. I think if i dont resolve it here it will turn into more severe error.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Here's the main class code:

```
package com.bilal.student.dal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StudentdalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudentdalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here's the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.bilal.student.dal</groupId>
<artifactId>studentdal</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>studentdal</name>
<description>STUDENT DAL</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the warning? I assume you're using an ide like eclipse or IntelliJ

Comment: Warning is that spring.datasource.url is an unknown property. I am using eclipse photon ide with mysql workbench.

Comment: The configuration file name should be application.properties and must be located in src/main/resources. Have you checked that? 
Have you tried running the app?

Comment: Yes application.properties are in the same folders you mentioned above. Yes i have tried to run the app and got the following error. Error: Could not find or load main class com.bilal.student.dal.StudentdalApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bilal.student.dal.StudentdalApplication

Comment: Could you show the code of your main class?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the main class' code

Comment: Main class code added at question.

Comment: Are you building the app with maven or gradle?

Comment: I am using maven for this build.

Comment: Do you have this plugin in your pom.xml file? 
`<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>` ?


Try running `mvn spring-boot:run` in a cmd or console from your application directory

Comment: Yes martin i have this plugin in pom.xml. I have also added pom.xml whole code in question.

Comment: Open a cmd or terminal. Go to your spring-boot app directory. Try running `mvn spring-boot:run` and tell me what you get.

Comment: I have done the same u asked i have opened my terminal and run this command mvn spring-boot:run. Nothing happened it show me unknown command.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the error @Martin Zaragoza. Actually problem was in my project build path. I have deleted the .m2 folder in my C:\Users\hp.m2 and all the error gone. Now i am successfully building my project. Thanks for sticking up with me.